# How can I make font size responsive in laravel's welcome.blaze.php?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

> ### This is what the word "LaravelProject" and its links, look like on a large screen, I like it to look that way, with all that space everywhere

> > [image]

---

> ### This is what a newly created Laravel project looks like on a small sized screen

> > [image]

---

> ### If you change the word "Laravel" for "LaravelProject" you won't even be able to see all the letters in small screens; also the links below the word get more space in between them, and collapse from 3 to 2 rows of links

> > [image]

---

> ### This laravel project is using bootstrap and vue, still, as I'm really new to ui, vue and bootstrap, I don't know how to solve the problem, this is the code where the "LaravelProject" comes from

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        LaravelProject
    </div>
<div class="navbar-brand">
    <div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="links">
    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
    <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
    <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com">Vapor</a>
    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
</div>
```

---

> ### And these are the style definitions for `content`, `title` & `m-b-md`

```
.title {
    font-size: 84px;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
}

.m-b-md {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

> ### How can I make that font to scale according to the screen size in laravel with vue/bootstrap? If there were 100 letters could that scale as well in large screens, etc? I'm sorry if this is a really noob question, I'm really new to web development outside of the .net framework! I want to improve my understanding according to how this work, and everything I read so far seems too technical for me and too oriented to other technologies, at least that's what I thought when searching for information on how to solve this.

Comment: This is not a laravel question but a CSS question

Comment: @FTW I changed the tags

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the text as big as possible, you can't do that without javascript. There is this plugin for instance https://brorlandi.github.io/big-text.js/ and at least another one that I can't find.

If you want the text not to be as big as possible but simple "big for the screen", you need to use a unit bound to the size of the container block (a percentage for instance) or even screen (vw, vh) or to the browser settings (rem typically).

1 vw = 1% of the "view" width.

1 rem = 1 x the default font size of the root element.

If you want something more custom depending on if the screen is big or medium or small, you're gonna need media queries. It's what bootstrap is using, but I don't think that bootstrap alone will let you do that. It's pretty simple and there are courses about it, such as https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

It will for instance let you have a text with 50vw for big screen, 80vh for medium screen, etc...

I advise you to test every possibility, to see what fits more your need.

Comment: (Updated my question...) I tried that already, but that's a static kind of solution... I mean OK, I can go and do `<h1 "style;vw=80">` and it will work nice on mobile, but it will make the font too big on a large screen, so I don't like it... can't I do something dynamic using css since that's the kinda question you say I'm doing; or bootstrap, which seems more reasonable to me? with dynamic I mean... occupy 80% if it's mobile, idk maybe 40% if it's a large screen?

Comment: answer updated with media queries, it's what you want.

Comment: I've seen that and I thought the same as you, doesn't look bootstrap sintax to me either. I googled before making my question... But let me investigate a little in that direction and I'll get back.

Comment: I'll upvote you, since I wasn't going to look back @ media queries (see what I did there? :) I ended up using those and finding exactly what I was looking for

Comment: good news ! don't forget to note your question as answered

Answer (score 1):

try vw or media

```css
.title {
font-size: 8vw;
}
================== OR ====================
@media(min-width: 768px) {
.title {
    font-size: 84px;
}
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
.title {
    font-size: 40px;
}
}
@media(max-width: 425px) {
.title {
    font-size: 30px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> #### I should have probably tried media queries when I saw them yesterday (never seen those before) but it didn't look like bootstrap to me... I guess I was too tired to try that out, until FTW suggested it to me minutes ago, then I thought: "let's give it a try!".

---

> #### This is the code: I really like the output now, in all the screen sizes I've tried so far!

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { 
    .title {
        font-size: 80vw;
    }
}

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .title {
        font-size: 80vw;
    }
}

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .title {
        font-size: 60vw;
    }
}

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .title {
        font-size: 40vw;
    }
}

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 2000.98px) {
    
}
```